# How to display data in a telerik grid?

Tags: mysql, .net

I'm using telerik controls and I want to display data based on a daterange in a gridview like this:

[image]

Comment: you need to create a controller action that gets the desired data

Answer (score 0):

On the UI, build your grid with the columns required. Add a click handler to the the button "Load".

```
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="Load" OnClick="btnLoad_Click" Text="Add"></telerik:RadButton>
```

In the click handler do this.

```
protected void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   grid.DataSource = db.tbl_name.Where(d => d.frm_dt == ui_frm_dt && d.to_dt == ui_to_dt).ToList();
}
```

The `ui_frm_dt` and `ui_to_dt` are the date fields that you have on the web page.

Let me know if this helps.